# Is it better to define vars outside of loops?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is the second better than the first?

**FIRST:**

```
var count:int=myArray.length;
for(var i:uint=0;i<count;i++)
{
   var str:String=myArray[i].label;
   var somethingElse:Class=...;
   var andAnotherThing:MyInstance=new MyInstance(somethingElse);
   ...
}
```

**SECOND:**

```
var count:int=myArray.length;
var str:String;
var somethingElse:Class;
var andAnotherThing:MyInstance;
for(var i:uint=0;i<count;i++)
{
   str=myArray[i].label;
   somethingElse=...;
   andAnotherThing=new MyInstance(somethingElse);
   ...
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: +1 Great question.. as I initially thought this was obvious, but have quickly realised through the other answers that it is far from obvious

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Actionscript and Javascript, variables are scoped to the function, not the block. It's called variable hoisting.

[ActionScript 3.0 Variables](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9d.html)

> An interesting implication of the lack of block-level scope is that
>   you can read or write to a variable before it is declared, as long as
>   it is declared before the function ends. This is because of a
>   technique called hoisting , which means that the compiler moves all
>   variable declarations to the top of the function.

So effectively your code will behave like this regardless of where you declare your variables within the function:

```
var count:int;
var str:String;
var i:uint;
var somethingElse:Class;
var andAnotherThing:MyInstance;

count = myArray.length;
for(i=0;i<count;i++)
{
   str=myArray[i].label;
   somethingElse = ...;
   andAnotherThing = new MyInstance(somethingElse);
   ...
}
```

Nevertheless, I still prefer to declare my variables within the blocks that use them  primarily for maintenance reasons and general clarity.

Comment: @Francisc Nope, they are not, you are setting the same variable for each iteration of the loop. You can verify this in the debugger, you'll see that the variables will contain the previous values at the start of each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

On Flash, the answer is it doesn't matter. Flash is weird when it comes to variable declaration.
Do the following and see what happens:

```
for(var i:uint=0;i<count;i++)
{
   var str:String=myArray[i].label;
   var somethingElse:Class=...;
   var andAnotherThing:MyInstance=new MyInstance(somethingElse);
}
var str:String=myArray[i].label;
```

Even though str ran out of scope out of the for loop, you will get a variable redefinition warning, meaning that the variable will only be "initialized" once in a for loop;

Answer (score 2):

ActionScript does not give execution blocks (like a `for` block) their own scope, unlike some other languages. The smallest scope for the variable is a function. So to the compiler, both of those examples are the same. In fact, the implementation is a technique called "variable hoisting", where the compiler moves the declaration of the variable before the beginning of the scope.

This has some interesting, if unexpected, side-effects; you can effectively "use" a variable before it has been "declared". For example:

```
trace(test);  // NaN
var test:Number = 10;
trace(test);  // 10
```

Notice that the first trace does not fail.

Anyway, the key thing to remember is that variables are locally scoped to functions. This is especially important when dealing with closures.

Answer (score 1):

In ActionScript 3 I don't think it really matters. I believe in other languages, loops have their own scope meaning that variables defined within them aren't accessible outside of the loop.

I think the only difference in AS3 is how it affects readability. In my opinion, the first example is much nicer.

Previously I often defined the iterator above the loop for readability purposes, like this:

```
var i:MovieClip;
for each(i in movieClipArray)
{
    trace(i);
}
```

But since getting into a variety of languages, I've kept everything contained for consistency:

```
for each(var i:MovieClip in movieClipArray)
{
    trace(i);
}
```